# Xamarin.iOS instantiate Storyboard Navigation controller in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I might be approaching this the wrong way, but I am trying to instantiate the NavigationController that I created in my storyboard into the AppDelegates FinishedLaunching method.

So, something like this:

```
 public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

        initialViewController = Storyboard.InstantiateInitialViewController () as UIViewController;

        window.RootViewController = initialViewController;
        window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();
        return true;
    }
```

but instead of a ViewController, I want to be instantiating the NavigationController.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Just set your navigation controller as the root controller in the storyboard. This is that little arrow (segue) pointing to the first controller.

You can then cast it with `as UINavigationViewController` if you need to.